# set JQuery action for each element spread

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a list of check boxes `Object { 0: div.checkbox-toggle, 1: div.checkbox-toggle, 2: div.checkbox-toggle, length: 3, prevObject: {…} }` and
each element is as `<div class="checkbox-toggle">...</div>`

in js file

```
...
var checkbox = $(".checkbox-toggle")

var ch = true
checkbox.change(function(){
  if (ch) {
    ch = false
    checkbox.css("background", "red")
  } else {
    ch = true
    checkbox.css("background", "green")

  }
})
```

I want to change only the color of checkbox which I clicks on, but now it change color of all checkboxes.
I'm wondring how to **set action for each checkbox independent**.
I also tried setting action with forloop, but couldn't get what i wanted.

Comment: Instead of `checkbox.css()` use `$(this).css()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the checkbox background on check click using the class toggle function. With the added css style below when the checkbox is clicked it will have green background if checked or red if not.

I wrapped the snippet in an IIFE to avoid any potential namespace corruption.

(vanilla solution though)

Add this inside `<head>`

```html
<style>
    .checkbox-toggle:not(.isChecked) {
        background: red;
    }
    .checkbox-toggle.isChecked {
        background: green;
    }
</style>
```

Add this before `</body>`

```html
<script>
    void function() {
        const checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName(".checkbox-toggle");
            
        for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
            void checkbox.classList.add('isChecked');

            checkbox.onclick = check;
        }
        
        function check(e) {
            const currentCheckbox = e.target || e.srcElement;
          
            void currentCheckbox.classList.toggle('isChecked');
        };
    }();
</script>
```